# How can I simulate 200 matrices (20*100) in R from a multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: r, simulation

I'm using the following code to simulate 20 observations for 100 predictor variables (features). I want to run the simulation 200 times. Somehow it doesn't feel right to add a second 'for' loop to create a list of matrices.
Do you have any suggestions on how to efficiently simulate several matrices from a multivariate normal distribution?

```
x <- matrix(rep(NA, 20*100), 20, 100)
for (i in 1:20) {
    x[i, ] <- mvrnorm(n = 1, mu = rep(0, 100), Sigma = diag(100)) 
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is about how to code in R, not about statistics. This Q should be asked on [SO]. If you wait a bit, we will migrate it there.

Comment: Use `list` structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lapply(1:200,function(x) rmvnorm( n=20, mean=rep(0,100), sigma=diag(100) ))
```

will give you a list of such matrices.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need no correlation, simply use

```
x = array( rnorm(200*20*100), dim=c(200,20,100) )
```

Your code could be abbreviated to

```
library(mvtnorm)
x <- rmvnorm( n=20, mean=rep(0,100), sigma=diag(100) )
```

Now in order to have 200 of such matrices, I suggest the outer 'for' loop:

```
x <- array( dim=c(200,20,100) )
for (i in 1:200) {
  x[i,,] <- rmvnorm( n=20, mean=rep(0,100), sigma=diag(100) )
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
Actually this makes it even simpler.
replicate (n = 200, expr = {data.frame(mvrnorm(n = 20, mu =  rep(0, 100), Sigma = diag(100))}, simplify = F)